How can I prevent Selenium from clicking "Show More" button too quickly before new content loads?
I’m trying to scrape data from a football site using Selenium, and I need to click the "Show more" button multiple times to load all the matches. The button disappears during loading and is replaced by a loader animation, but my script is clicking the button too quickly in succession before the new content has fully loaded. This causes multiple clicks without actually loading the data.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import time

service = Service("C:\\Users\\sddd\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://oddspedia.com/football")

try:
    # Accept cookies
    cookie_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="cookie-popup__btn"]'))
    )
    cookie_button.click()
    print("Cookies accepted.")

    while True:
        try:
            show_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ml-show-more-btn"]/button'))
            )
            show_more_button.click()
            print("Clicked 'Show more' button.")

            WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'loader'))
            )

            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'loader'))
            )

            time.sleep(1)  # Optional: slight pause to ensure content is ready
            print("Loading completed, ready for next click.")

        except TimeoutException:
            print("No more 'Show more' button or page loading timeout.")
            break

except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Element not found.")
finally:
    driver.quit()


How can I modify this script to make Selenium wait for the new content to load before clicking the "Show more" button again? Are there better ways to ensure the page has finished loading new data before attempting another click?

Usually you can wait for the new elements loaded and presented in the html source. give a simple example, the page load 3 list elements every time you click the "show more" button. It shows 3 list by default.
So you need wait the element with XPath "//ul/li[" + (clickedCount + 1) *3 + "]" present.
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

The initialized "clickedCount = 0" before while statement.
Every time the button clicked. Then
clickedCount = clickedCount + 1
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//ul/li[' + (clickedCount + 1) *3 + ']'))
        )


It needed some adjustments between clicking and display locations and timing.
The biggest problem is that the site does not respond to a click action on the 'Show more' button when entered with selenium. Just run a program that stops at the end of "cookie_button.click()", and click manually on the 'Show more' button. Then you will find that the site won't load new data. So it seemed to me that this subject cannot be solved.
But today, I found the site which had been opened yesterday responded to manual clicks. Through some tests I knew that it takes several minutes for the site to respond to manual clicks after opened by selenium.
The following program waits until the site responds, clicking every 30 minutes. It takes about 16 minutes.
By comparing the length of elements, the program can know if a click has been effective or not.
In order to click the button, we have to scroll it to a visible position.
"driver.execute_script('arguments[0]. ..." and "actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)..." play this roll.
Every browser action takes longer time than python takes to go to next line. So, "sleep()" are inserted where necessary.
When you use the "try:" over multiple lines, the system does not give error messages except for the defined in the "except:" clause. This is the reason why I eliminated it.
It is for my convenience that I used Firefox, of course you can use Chrome driver.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
from time import sleep
from datetime import  datetime

#service = Service("C:\\Users\\sddd\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe")
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("https://oddspedia.com/football")
print ('\nstart: ', datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ,'\n')
sleep(5)

# Accept cookies
cookie_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="cookie-popup__btn"]'))
)
cookie_button.click()
print("Cookies accepted.")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
divs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ml__wrap"]/div')
pre_len = len(divs)
print('number of div elements: {}\n'.format(pre_len))
print('Wait for about 16 minutes until button click turns allowed\n')

stage = 0
for s in range(60):
    try:
        #check the existence of the button
        show_more_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ml-show-more-btn"]/button')
    except:
        print("\nNo more 'Show more' button.\nProgram ends.")
        break
    else:
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end"});', show_more_button)
        sleep(1)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()#PAGE_DOWN
        #actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()#ARROW_DOWN
        sleep(1)
        show_more_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ml-show-more-btn"]/button')
        show_more_button.click()
        print("Clicked 'Show more' button.")
        sleep(1)

        divs= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ml__wrap"]/div')
        #while the loading continues, 'implicitly_wait' functions

        if len(divs) > pre_len:
            #case data increased
            pre_len = len(divs)
            stage = 1
            
            print('\nNew data loaded: ', datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ,'\n')
            print('number of div elements: {}\n'.format(pre_len))
            
            sleep(1)
        else:
            #case data not increased
            if stage == 0:
                sleep(30)
                #
            else:
                sleep(1)

